# IIF and isNothing

Tags: vb.net, null, iif

I have 3 textboxes that i want to concatenate. fname, mname, lname

For example:

```
fname = Nat    ----     mname = Arnido    ----   lname = Congreso
```

then i want them to concatenate  in other textbox called fullname using a command button.

```
fullname = Congreso, Nat A.
```

But in the other case where middle name is null the fullname should look like this.

```
fullname = Congreso, Nat
```

and i find it difficult to remove the period (.) in the middle name.

This is my code so far.

```
Me.fullname.Text = Me.lname.Text & ", " & Me.fname.Text & " " & IIf(IsNothing(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(Me.mname.Text, 1) & ""), "", (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(Me.mname.Text, 1)) & ". ")
```

Comment: The Iif method has for most purposes been replaced by the [If operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textbox data is usually not `Nothing`. It is at most an empty string:

```
Me.fullname.Text = Me.lname.Text & ", " & _
                   Me.fname.Text &  _
                   If(Me.mname.Text = String.Empty, _
                       "", _
                       " " & Left(Me.mname.Text, 1) & ".")
```

Comment: yeah.. thank you so much for your fast response. Ive been struggling for this code for about 3 days already.. thank you so much

Comment: See Andrew's comment in the OP.

Comment: `Left` is **VB6 legacy code**. You better use `" " & mname.Text.Chars(0) & ".")`

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use IIf or Left.

```
    fullname.Text = lname.Text.Trim & ", " & fname.Text.Trim
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mname.Text) Then
        fullname.Text &= " " & mname.Text.Trim.Substring(0, 1) & "."
    End If
```

If I were enamored of writing this as one long statement I would use the If operator.

```
    fullname.Text = lname.Text.Trim & ", " & fname.Text.Trim & _
        If(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mname.Text.Trim), " " & mname.Text.Substring(0, 1) & ".", "")
```

Comment: I'd use `mname.Text.Chars(0)` instead of `mname.Text.Substring(0, 1)`, since I find it more intuitive. And it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the String `Replace` method to remove/change any unwanted characters/patterns.

```
mname.Replace(".", "")
```

Comment: If mname is empty how does this help?

Comment: Simply check if it is or not before trying to add to the fullname string variable.

`fullname.Text &= If(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mname),  String.Empty, mname.Replace(".", ""))`

If would be far better to investigate the StringBuilder class however. http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-vbnet